# 3g modem randomly disconnects on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, modem, 3g, disconnect

i am using D-link modem with BSNL sim card and it took some changes to get it recognized as a modem and ultimately the sakis script got it to work pretty well. i still am using network manager to connect and disconnect. it will run sometimes twenty minutes, more often about an hour, and once or twice it kept running til i had to sign off. i can usually get it connected again, but it will not run very long after it has disconnected itself. what command line can i run to tell me what the problem is? or does anyone recognize what i need to do to fix it? i am not entirely literate in linux so please keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

If the modem disappears from the Network Manager applet, once automatically disconnected:

> It usually happens due to poor signal strength or wrecked USB ports. Try plugging the 3g dongle to a USB port you've rarely used. Run **sudo pkill modem-manager** if you want to re-detect the dongle.

If the problem still exists:

> Try installing proprietary (manufacturer's) drivers which should come with your device.

By the way, mention the model of your dongle using **lsusb** command.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for solution of similar problem. My usb 3G modem was disconnecting and connecting all over again and again, sometimes successfully, sometimes not. Working on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, but had the same issue on 18.04.

Solution in my case was to change IOMMU settings in UEFI bios to "disabled". This is specific to UEFI bios motherboard types as far as I know.

My motherboard: Gigabyte 970A-DS3P.

I use Modem Manager GUI to control usb modem connection which works very well.

Modem:

- HSDPA USB Modem 29 
  (listed in GUI Manager)
- Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E161/E169/E620/E800 HSDPA Modem
   (listed
  by running `lsusb` in bash terminal).